# how to get output from data frames in R code

Tags: r, dataframe, matrix, vector, data-analysis

I have the following code to analyze data sets:

```
library("Matrix")


Data <-list(c(2,3),c(3,2),c(2,2))
TheSizes=c(3,4)
n=2
dd=2

StdGrid <- function(Data,TheSizes)
{
  SGrid <- list(
    Values = Data,
    Sizes = TheSizes
  )
  class(SGrid) <- append(class(SGrid), c("StdGrid","Moment"))
  return(SGrid)
}

theObject=StdGrid


MHistogramC <- function(theObject,n,dd)
{
  sizes <- theObject$Sizes
  l <- length(sizes)
  data <- theObject$Values
  Xarray <- matrix(rep(0,l*n),ncol=n)
  N <- matrix(rep(0,l*n),ncol=n)
  Histo <- matrix(rep(0,l*n),ncol=n)
  GrandX <- lapply(data,function(x) log(x))
  minX <- rep(0,l)
  maxX <- rep(0,l)
  DeltaX <- rep(0,l)
  for(i in 1:l){
    minX[i] <- min(GrandX[[i]])
    maxX[i] <- max(GrandX[[i]])
    DeltaX[i] <- maxX[i]/n-minX[i]/n
  }
  nzero <- numeric()
  for(j in 1:n){
    for(i in 1:l){
      Xarray[i,j] <- minX[i]+(j-1/2)*DeltaX[i]
      N[i,j] <- length(which((GrandX[[i]] >= minX[i]+(j-1/2)*DeltaX[i]-DeltaX[i]) & (GrandX[[i]] <= minX[i]+(j-1/2)*DeltaX[i]+DeltaX[i])))
      Histo[i,j] <- log(N[i,j])
    }
    if(min(Histo[,j]) > - 10000){
      nzero <- c(nzero,j)
    }
  }
  alpha <- rep(0,lnzero)
  falpha <- rep(0,lnzero)
  for(j in 1:length(nzero)){
    fit <- lm(Xarray[,nzero[j]] ~ log(sizes/dd))
    alpha[j] <- fit$coefficients[[2]]
    fit2 <- lm(Histo[,nzero[j]] ~ log(sizes/dd))
    falpha[j] <- -fit2$coefficients[[2]]
  }
  Result <- data.frame(alpha=alpha,falpha=falpha)
  return(Result)
}

MHistogramU <- function(theObject,n,dd)
{
  sizes <- theObject$Sizes
  l <- length(sizes)
  data <- theObject$Values
  Xarray <- matrix(rep(0,l*n),ncol=n)
  N <- matrix(rep(0,l*n),ncol=n)
  Histo <- matrix(rep(0,l*n),ncol=n)
  GrandX <- lapply(data,function(x) log(x))
  minX <- rep(0,l)
  maxX <- rep(0,l)
  DeltaX <- rep(0,l)
  for(i in 1:l){
    minX[i] <- min(GrandX[[i]])
    maxX[i] <- max(GrandX[[i]])
    DeltaX[i] <- maxX[i]/n-minX[i]/n
  }
  nzero <- numeric()
  for(j in 1:n){
    for(i in 1:l){
      Xarray[i,j] <- minX[i]+(j-1/2)*DeltaX[i]
      N[i,j] <- length(which((GrandX[[i]] >= minX[i]+(j-1/2)*DeltaX[i]-sqrt(DeltaX[i])) & (GrandX[[i]] <= minX[i]+(j-1/2)*DeltaX[i]+sqrt(DeltaX[i]))))
      Histo[i,j] <- log(N[i,j])
    }
    if(min(Histo[,j]) > - 10000){
      nzero <- c(nzero,j)
    }
  }
  alpha <- rep(0,lnzero)
  falpha <- rep(0,lnzero)
  for(j in 1:length(nzero)){
    fit <- lm(Xarray[,nzero[j]] ~ log(sizes/dd))
    alpha[j] <- fit$coefficients[[2]]
    fit2 <- lm(Histo[,nzero[j]] ~ log(sizes/dd))
    falpha[j] <- -fit2$coefficients[[2]]
  }
  Result <- data.frame(alpha=alpha,falpha=falpha)
  return(Result)
}
```

Which compiles, but i don't get anything in return. If I try to print "Result" the console says that the object "Result" was not found.
The inputs are:

> Data : is a list of vector/grids
>
> TheSizes : is a vector
>
> theObject : the data defined as the class 'StdGrid' (defined below);
>
> n : the number of values of alpha to be calculated;
>
> dd : the dimension of the physical support of the measure.

What can I do to see the data frame that the code is supposed to return?

Comment: did you call the function you wrote?

Answer (score 0):

That is because your code is just a bunch of functions which are not called at all. A function would return value only when the function is called, it won't call itself.

Now looking at your code, It's hard to deduce what you are trying to calculate/analyze, but assuming all other codes are correct, and all functions are coded perfectly, you need to add the following lines to view the result at the end of your code:

```
var_MHistogramU <- MHistogramU(theObject,n,dd)
var_MHistogramC <- MHistogramC(theObject,n,dd)
```

To view the result, simply print the variables.

```
print(var_MHistogramU)
print(var_MHistogramC)
```

Remember: Printing Result won't work as the variable result is a local variable for the function, which is inaccessible globally.